# Primefaces 5 fileupload event triggered for alternate requests alone

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I am using primefaces 5 and a simple p:fileupload tag is triggering the event only for alternate requests. The event is triggered for 1st 3rd and so on, and not on 2nd 4th etc.  This is happening for mode=simple/advanced, auto=true/false, multiple=true/false. Id multiple = true and then i select 4/5 files only 2/3 file events are triggered.

Is it a known issue? Or am i missing any configuration?

Primeface 5
Apache tomcat 7
jars in tomcat 7

```
all-themes-1.0.10.jar
annotations-api.jar
antlr-2.7.2.jar
bsf-2.3.0.jar
catalina-ant.jar
catalina-ha.jar
catalina-tribes.jar
catalina.jar
commons-beanutils-1.8.0.jar
commons-chain-1.2.jar
commons-digester-1.8.jar
commons-fileupload-1.2.2.jar
commons-io-2.4.jar
commons-logging-1.0.4.jar
commons-net-3.3.jar
ecj-P20140317-1600.jar
el-api.jar
jasper-el.jar
jasper.jar
jsf-api-2.2.7.jar
jsf-impl-2.2.7.jar
jsp-api.jar
jstl-1.2.jar
oro-2.0.8.jar
primefaces-5.0.jar
servlet-api.jar
standard-1.0.6.jar
tomcat-api.jar
tomcat-coyote.jar
tomcat-dbcp.jar
tomcat-i18n-es.jar
tomcat-i18n-fr.jar
tomcat-i18n-ja.jar
tomcat-jdbc.jar
tomcat-util.jar
tomcat7-websocket.jar
websocket-api.jar
```

Below is the test.xhtml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

<h:head>
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <h1>Hello World PrimeFaces</h1>

    <h:form enctype="multipart/form-data">
       <p:fileUpload fileUploadListener="#{ftpBean.upload1}"/>
    </h:form>

</h:body>
</html>
```

FTPBean.java is

```
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;

@ManagedBean(name="ftpBean")
@ViewScoped
public class FTPBean implements Serializable {
   public void upload1(FileUploadEvent event) {
        System.out.println("Saved files: " + localFile);
   }
}
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
 id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
 <display-name>ATR</display-name>
<context-param>
      <param-name>primefaces.THEME</param-name>
      <param-value>aristo</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.PARTIAL_STATE_SAVING</param-name>
    <param-value>false</param-value>
</context-param>
<listener>
 <listener-class>com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener</listener-class>
 </listener>

<filter>
  <filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
  <filter-class>org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
  <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
</filter-mapping>

<!-- Faces Servlet -->
 <servlet>
 <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
 <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
 <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
 </servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
 <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
 <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

faces-config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <faces-config xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_0.xsd"
 version="2.0">
    <managed-bean>
      <description>UsernName Bean</description>
      <managed-bean-name>user</managed-bean-name>
      <managed-bean-class>demo.User</managed-bean-class>
      <managed-bean-scope>request</managed-bean-scope>
      <managed-property>
         <property-name>name</property-name>
         <property-class>java.lang.String</property-class>
         <value/>
      </managed-property>
   </managed-bean>
</faces-config>
```

Comment: What do you see in the network traffic (on your browser's js console) for the even number-cycle requests?